# object key deleted but still iterated in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Given EcmaScript Section 12.6.4:

> Properties of the object being enumerated may be deleted during
>   enumeration. If a property that has not yet been visited during
>   enumeration is deleted, then it will not be visited.

However, check out this case:

```
class Lead {
    MAPPINGS = [
        [
            /Medication_Types_(\d+)/,
            (data, key, acc, i) => {
                const values = Object.keys(data)
                                     .filter( key => /Medication_Types_(\d+)/.test(key ))
                                     .map(key => data[key]);

                console.log('the values: ', values);
                acc['Medication_Types'] = values;

                Object.keys(data).forEach( key => {
                    if( /Medication_Types_(\d+)/.test(key)) delete data[key];
                })

                return i;
            }
        ]
    ]

    format(data) {
        const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        let mapping = false;
        let i = 1;

        const result = Object.keys(copy).reduce((acc, key) => {
            mapping = false;
            this.MAPPINGS.forEach( (mapping) => {
                if(mapping[0].test(key)){
                    mapping[1](copy, key, acc, i);
                    mapping = true;
                }
            });

            if(!mapping){
                acc[key] = copy[key];
            }

            return acc;
        }, {});

        return result;
    }
}

const data = {
    "Gender" : "Male",
    "Medication_Types_1" : "A",
    "Medication_Types_2" : "B",
    "First_Name" : "bob"
}

const lead = new Lead();
const result = lead.format(data);
console.log('the result: ', result);
```

It outputs:

```
the values:  [ 'A', 'B' ]
the values:  []
the result:  {
  Gender: 'Male',
  Medication_Types: [],
  Medication_Types_1: undefined,
  Medication_Types_2: undefined,
  First_Name: 'bob'
}
```

If the keys were truly deleted, then "the values" would have not printed the second time and instead I would have gotten (and what I want) this:

```
{
      Gender: 'Male',
      Medication_Types: ['A', 'B'],
      First_Name: 'bob'
}
```

So it seems like `delete` might be deleting the key but not from the current iteration, but EcmaScript states it will delete from the current iteration! What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What EcmaScript version are you citing? In the [current revision](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-exp-operator-static-semantics-assignmenttargettype), §12.6.2 has nothing to do with enumeration.

Comment: @Bergi I was citing 5 not 6 by accident. But I assume if it was in 5, it would be in 6.

Comment: The current revision is 10, and enumeration is described via an iterator there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing an enumeration. You are creating an array, and then deleting the properties during the `forEach` iteration of that array:

```
const keys = Object.keys(data);
console.log(keys); // at this point, all the keys are already in the array
keys.forEach( key => {
    if( /Medication_Types_(\d+)/.test(key)) delete data[key];
})
```

When you `delete` the property from the object, it does not get removed from the `keys` array. Same happens in your `reduce` call. You could avoid that by using a real `for … in` loop.

---

However, the actual bug in your code is

```
mapping = false;
this.MAPPINGS.forEach((mapping) => {
//                      ^^^^^^^
    if (mapping[0].test(key)){
        mapping[1](copy, key, acc, i);
        mapping = true;
//      ^^^^^^^
    }
});
```

where you do not set the outer-scope boolean `mapping` variable to `true` that would prevent the value getting copied into the result, but instead you just overwrite the `mapping` parameter of your `forEach` callback.

Comment: probably the best solution then would be to create a groupBy function  (and group related keys) before enumeration?

Comment: @Donato Possibly. I've taken a deeper look at your question and found that the unexpected result is due to a different bug, and not related to the non-deletion of the property.

Comment: The reuse of mapping false was an unintentional consequence when copying over the code into SO. The original issue still occurred even when mapping was a different value. The real issue was that I was mutating an object, but iterating over the array. Good eye to notice that. My quick solution was to work with array and use splice function for removal of items.